# Add text to container to fill it as it resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, resize

Say I have a div that is `200px` wide and `50px` high, and has text contents that say "Hello, World!" that fit in the div edge-to-edge, top to bottom.  I'm using jQuery UI Resizable to allow this div to be expanded.  I want to add text to the div as it is expanded.  If the div were resized to be `400px` wide, the contents would be "Hello World!Hello World!", as that text will not fit twice.

Some example code to get started:

```
<div class="resize-me" style="height: 50px; width: 200px;">
    Hello, World!
</div>

$(".resize-me").resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui){
        // Logic here to dynamically add/remove/show/hide text as the div
        // is resized
    }
});
```

Comment: is the resize factor constant or dynamic?

Comment: The container will always be resized to the left-right, or straight down, by the pixel (standard resize event of jQuery UI resizable).

Answer (score 0):

how about leave the `overflow:hidden` in the css and scale according to width ?

```
<div class="resize-me" style="height: 50px; width: 200px; overflow:hidden;">
    Hello, World!
</div>

$(".resize-me").resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui){
        $(this).text(ui.size.width*"Hello World!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ideally, it wouldn't have half-words or half-letters at the edge where it gets cut off.

Comment: @MikeTrpcic have you had a look at the [text-overflow attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) yet? Try the ellipsis example.